Encounters ld error when compiling a simple C++ source file which involves icu::UnicodeString on Windows
I want to use icu::UnicodeString in ICU to handle unicode strings. And I wrote a simple demo .cpp file to test if I could compile with ICU libraries.
The content of demo.cpp is below:
#include <unicode/unistr.h>
#include <unicode/utypes.h>
#include <unicode/ustream.h>

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main(){
    icu::UnicodeString str("akeywords", 9, icu::UnicodeString::kInvariant);

    cout << str << endl;
}

I use the constructor icu::UnicodeString::UnicodeString(const char *   src, int32_t textLength, enum EInvariant inv) to initialize an object.
Then, I tried a compile command:
g++ demo.cpp -o demo.exe -I"D:\ICU\include" -L"D:\ICU\lib64" -licuin -licuuc -licuio


And it reported the error information below:
D:/Program Files (x86)/MinGW-64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-
w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:\msys2\tmp\ccVyQ2L3.o:test2.cpp:(.text+0x2b): undefined reference to `icu_
74::UnicodeString::UnicodeString(char const*, int, icu_74::UnicodeString::EInvariant)'
D:/Program Files (x86)/MinGW-64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-
w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:\msys2\tmp\ccVyQ2L3.o:test2.cpp:(.text+0x41): undefined reference to `icu_
74::operator<<(std::ostream&, icu_74::UnicodeString const&)'
D:/Program Files (x86)/MinGW-64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-
w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:\msys2\tmp\ccVyQ2L3.o:test2.cpp:(.text+0x5f): undefined reference to `icu_
74::UnicodeString::~UnicodeString()'
D:/Program Files (x86)/MinGW-64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-
w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:\msys2\tmp\ccVyQ2L3.o:test2.cpp:(.text+0x75): undefined reference to `icu_
74::UnicodeString::~UnicodeString()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status


Envronment

OS: Windows 10
Compiler: g++ with version of 13.2.0
ICU version: 74

ICU Settings

Install Method: Download a .zip file contains package compiled with MSVC and then unzip it to my machine.
Install Path: D:\\ICU
Directory Structure:

D:\\ICU
      ├─bin
      ├─lib64
      ├─include
      ├─APIChangeReport.html
      ├─icu4c.css
      ├─LICENSE
      ├─readme.html

Efforts

Tried to add compile options licuio, while it didn't work.

Supplementary
Before I encountered the problem above, I successfully compiled a tiny cpp demo which involves UCharsetDetector of icu(which is a pure C API). And it runs without abortion(seems no problem).
The demo's code is below:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unicode/ucsdet.h>
#include <unicode/ucnv.h>
#include <unicode/utypes.h>
using namespace std;


int main(){
    string buf;
    cin>>buf;
    UErrorCode status = U_ZERO_ERROR;
    UCharsetDetector *detector = ucsdet_open(&status);


    ucsdet_setText(detector, buf.c_str(), buf.length(), &status);
    if (U_FAILURE(status)) {
        cerr << "Failed when setting text: " << u_errorName(status) << endl;
        return 1;
    }


    const UCharsetMatch * matcher = ucsdet_detect(detector, &status);
    
    
    if (U_FAILURE(status)) {
        cerr << "Failed when detect the text" << u_errorName(status) << endl;
        return 1;
    }


    const char* encoding = ucsdet_getName(matcher, &status);
    int32_t confidence = ucsdet_getConfidence(matcher, &status);


    cout << "the encoding: " << encoding << endl;
    cout << "the confidence: " << confidence << endl;


    free(detector);
    

    return 0;

}

And I run the command below to compile with g++:
g++ demo.cpp -o demo.exe -I"D:\ICU\include" -L"D:\ICU\lib64" -licuin -licuuc

And it can output the detection result.
I run all the compile commands in msys2, and I am convinced that the environments variables are set appropriately.
The Solution and the end
Thanks to the suggestion given from the comments, I finally figured out the reason caused such Error.
The Error is caused by trying to link the libraries built by MSVC to the target while compiling with g++. And due to the C API's portability, that behaviour didn't report any errors or warnings when compiled the codes in Supplementary.
Therefore, to address the problem, what I need to do is just build the libraries of ICU via Mingw64 toolchain. I eventually addressed the problem.
--10/27/2024

Not sure, but my guess is that you downloaded incompatible libraries. Are you using MSYS2? If not you should be. And if you are using MSYS2 then you should use it's package manager tool to install ICU. That way you are sure to get compatible libraries.

"...compiled with MSVC..."  and g++ demo.cpp...  you are mixing tool-chains.  You need to compile both with the same tool-chain.

By the way, I successfully compiled another tiny cpp demo which involves icu charsetdetector. Thus, I can basicall ensure that my pre-built icu is compatible with my system and compiler.(The code and the compile command will be appended to the detail above)

you can't use a c++ library intended for a different compiler, your working code is only using the c API which is more portable between compilers
